# Function to print all combination of entered characters is not printing as expected

Tags: c, recursion

The goal of my program is to print all combinations of characters that a user may enter as long as it is under the max length. I am able to correctly fill the array with characters, show the number of characters entered, and the max length of the string (entered by the user). However, the functions do not print as expected. In theory if the user entered **2 characters (a, b) with a max length of 2**, the program should output this...

```
a
b
aa
ab
ba
bb
```

Instead, my code is outputting this and I can not figure out why...

```
a
ab
```

Below are my two functions. My main function gets the user input for the number of characters, the character array, and the max length of the string to be printed out. After, it calls the **generatePassword** function. Any help would be appreciated!

```
int crack(char *characters[], int i, char s[], int numCharacters, int passwordLength) {
    if (i==0) {
        printf("%s\n", s);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numCharacters; j++) {
        char string[MAX];
        strcpy(string, strcat(s, characters[j]));
        crack(characters, i-1, string, numCharacters, passwordLength);
    }
    return 0;
}


void generatePassword(char* characters[], int numCharacters, int passwordLength) {

    for (int i = 1; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        char s[MAX] = "";
        int num = crack(characters, i, s, numCharacters, passwordLength);
    }

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("ERROR: Program did not execute due to lack of arguments.\n");
                return -1;
        }

        int numCharacters;
        numCharacters = atoi(argv[1]);
        int passwordLength;
        passwordLength = atoi(argv[numCharacters+2]);

        for (int i = 0; i < numCharacters; i++) {
                if (strlen(argv[i+2]) > 1) {
                        printf("ERROR: You can only input one character at a time.\n");
                        return -1;
                }
        }

        if (argc != (numCharacters+3)) {
                printf("ERROR: Invalid number of arguments.\n");
                return -1;
        }

        char *charArray[numCharacters];

        for (int i = 0; i < numCharacters; i++) {
                charArray[i] = argv[i+2];
        }

        generatePassword(charArray, numCharacters, passwordLength);
        return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I have added my main function to the code to show how I call generatePassword. The goal of the code is to get the number of characters going to be entered, the characters, and the max length of the string from the command line in the linux environment.

Comment: What is the value of `characters`?

Comment: also please consider adding a little bit of documentation on your code to makes it more readable to people who don't have written it

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right, sorry

Comment: Can you show us how `generatePassword` is called. Why do you have a variable called `numCharacters` that is actually the number of strings in `characters`? Do you provide each character as its own string? So `numCharacters` is both the number of characters and the number of strings?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have a variable named `numCharacters` because that is the number of characters that are taken from the command line. I have included my main function to show how `generatePassword`

Comment: @Barmar the value of `characters` is taken from the command line. For example, if I ran my progam in linux with `./main 2 a b 2`, the `characters` would have a value of `a` and `b` for `characters[0]` and `characters[1]` respectively

Comment: `argv[i+1]` should be `argv[i+2]`

Comment: You're writing outside the array bounds here: `charArray[numCharacters] = (char*)malloc(numCharacters * sizeof(char));`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need to allocate memory there in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar I was getting an error when I was first writing the main function earlier, so I included it to be sure. I removed the line from the program.

Comment: If you try with more characters and longer password length, you'll see that the results always start with the first character, and they're always in order. You never move to a new starting point or process the characters out of order. That may help you track down the design problem.

Comment: BTW, what is the return value of `crack()` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void generatePassword(char* characters[], int numCharacters, int passwordLength) {

    for (int i = 1; i < passwordLength; i++) {
```

Your problem is right here. If `passwordLength` is two, you need to add two characters. But this loop will only run once if `passwordLength` is two. You want:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
```

Output is now:

> a
>   b
>   aa
>   ab
>   ba
>   bb

There are a few other bugs, such as your misuse of `strcat` and some off-by-one errors with argument indexes. You can see it working with all the bugs fixed [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SyZxYE3DI).

Comment: fantastic, that fixed it! Thank you for taking the time and fixing some other bugs as well, I've been stuck on this code forever. Cheers!

Comment: By the way, the key debugging technique I used was adding `printf` statement at key points to see where the code's behavior diverged from what I was expecting.

Comment: that is a method I will definitely be incorporating more often. I used it when I was writing the main function because I was having difficulty getting the correct input from the command line, but I should have continued to use it throughout my code. Thank you!